# How to format currency number to 2 decimal places, or none if no cents?

Tags: android, kotlin, number-formatting, decimalformat

I want to format a currency number to 2 decimal places if there are cents, or no decimal places if there are none.

For example, 1 would show as $1.
1.1 would show as $1.10.

Is there an easy way to do this in Android with Kotlin?

I've used `DecimalFormat("$#,###,##0.##)`. The main issue with this is 1.1 would appear as $1.1. Tried to also use `DecimalFormat($#,###,##0.#0)` app crashes because it says I can't after the `0` after the `#` at the 12th position.

Comment: Can you update your question to include some code of what you've tried? Have you tried using DecimalFormat? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826439/show-decimal-of-a-double-only-when-needed

Comment: I've updated the post with the DecimalFormat code I've tried to use.

Comment: Here are two questions that ask the same thing (although most of the answers are unsuitable, as they'd format `1` as `1.00`) https://stackoverflow.com/q/39267621/4161471 https://stackoverflow.com/q/2379221/4161471

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Java and Kotlin work hand in hand here is a **Java Solution**

One way of doing this would be to check if decimal number is similar to its `int` or `long` value

```java
if (number == (int) number)
      {
          NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat ("##");
          System.out.println (formatter.format (number));
      }
else
      {
          NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat ("##.00");
          System.out.println (formatter.format (number));
      }
```